# 2 files found with path 'META-INF/gradle/incremental.annotation.processors'. while using dagger hilt in android

Tags: android, build.gradle, dagger-hilt

`I am getting below error while building the app after adding dagger hilt dependency

> 2 files found with path
> 'META-INF/gradle/incremental.annotation.processors'. Adding a
> packagingOptions block may help, please refer to
> https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/8.1/com/android/build/api/dsl/ResourcesPackagingOptions
> for more information

I added below plugins and dependency in app build.gradle.kts file

```
plugins
id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
kotlin("kapt")

dependencies
implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44")
implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.44")
```

I have tried to change the below values in different ways.

`excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"` in packaging in gradle file.

I tried to change the value to `excludes +="\*\*/\*"`
After changing this app is building successfully. But getting runtime exception. Thats Hilt BaseApplication not found.

```
BaseApplication extends Application

@HiltAndroidApp
class BaseApplication:Application()
```

Added this in Manifest file too
android:name=".BaseApplication"

Answer (score 0):

well try to use **kapt** instead of implementation  for the hilt-compiler as follows :

```
implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44")
kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.44")
```

gonna work like charming (Y)

reference : https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android